# FireStore - Delete posts after 4 weeks

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Cloud functions, so forgive me if I don't make much sense or this is a simple question.

Users write to my database, within my app. Each post a user uploads has a node like so:

```
date: 1602712842.001008
```

I wish to delete posts that are 4 weeks/30 days old. I am using XCode and FireStore. I found this repo:

[Here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/delete-old-child-nodes/functions/index.js)

And I think it's what I'm after. However, the CUT_OFF_TIME variable is confusing, I believe it may be using CronJob? I've visited CronTab and after tampering with the calculator, this is what I need:

```
0 0 * * *
```

This means the function should execute at midnight, everyday. Which is exactly what I want. However, I've seen CronJob and the term PubSub pop up. I visited the repo link on GitHub to allow CronJob, as I believe FireStore doesn't directly support it? However, the repo advised not to use in production as it isn't maintained. So I'm confused as to how to implement it? I do have Cloud Functions installed. Just need a cloud function that is invoked every day, at midnight and delete posts that are 4 weeks or 30 days old/older.

I know I can't just write a cloud function where it will automatically schedule. Any help or advice? I wish to do this from the server/firestore. I can delete posts within my app, however,  I want the backend to remove any and all posts that are 4 weeks/30 days old.

Thank you.

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/jckq94/firestore_cloud_functions_how_to_delete_posts/

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly write your own scheduled function to query for and delete documents that are old.  You should start with the [documentation for scheduled functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).  Your function will start like this:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *').onRun((context) => {
    // add your logic here to query for an delete documents
});
```

It should be pretty straightforward to implement.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So I can use what you just said in-combination with the Gist I found, as long as I convert 30 days into milli seconds?

Comment: Sure, you can try that.

Comment: I have done, but it's not working. I posted another question, I have an error.